# What do you have to be careful about when migrating a UA account to the same URL but a new website?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, universal-analytics

Off the top of my head I can think of:

- [301 Redirects](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31245/how-does-google-rank-priority-for-not-found-errors) (some pages are the same pages, but they might have a different URL)

Should I use a new UA account and import the data into it, or use the same UA identification number?

What happens to existing goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of care, you should be fine to keep the same property if it's a new website on the same domain. Some of the major areas to consider are:

- **Implementation Issues**: If your new website is heavily dependent on AJAX, you may need to establish [Single Page Application Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications).
- **Event Tracking**: You'll need to reconfigure any event tracking you previously had, especially if you have event goals set up.
- **Behavior Flow**: If users are navigating to different URLs (but the equivalent page of the old website), this will skew your Behavior Flow data and show a large influx of traffic to new pages. One countermeasure you can take to help mitigate this issue (aside from renaming the page and/or establishing a 301 redirect) is to create a Search and Replace filter for the request URI, which allows you to keep the new pages as they are but replace the request URI field in Google Analytics with the name of the old page. You should only do this in a new view and not in the **All Web Site Data** view.

These are just a few things to consider and are not intended to be a complete list.